# Is there an easy way to find all dependencies of a framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

While writing extensions in Swift / categories in Objective-C I have to decide on a structured way to organize them in my Xcode project. I thought it would be a good idea to take the dependencies of the different Apple frameworks into account.

Let's look for example at the `MKMapView` class of the `MapKit` framework. It has a property `centerCoordinate` that has the type `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. And `CLLocationCoordinate2D` belongs to the `CoreLocation` framework. **Thus the `MapKit` framework depends on the `CoreLocation` framework.**

(See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/centerCoordinate)

I know that I can browse the corresponding header files to gather the information that I'm looking for. But this is quite tedious.

**Is there somewhere an overview of the dependencies of all Apple frameworks that come with the iOS / MacOS SDKs? Or an more convenient way to determine them?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Running [`otool`](http://www.manpages.info/macosx/otool.1.html) (I cannot find the official manpage) with the `-L` option over the framework binary should give you all dependencies:

```
$ otool -L /path/to/ABC.framework/Versions/Current/ABC
```